# Reference with a dynamic tag

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, tags

I have a list of several conditions with a parameter, and I would like to include the parameter explicitly in tag of the condition. However, I would also like to reference the definition of each condition (with the parameter fixed) later in the text. (It's a bit hard to describe, but if you look at the code below, it should hopefully be clear what I mean.)

Can this be accomplished using enumitem (or some other, hopefully compatible package)?

Mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    Consider the following conditions:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman{*})$_n$]
        \item
        \label{item:first_condition}
        Some condition
        \item
        \label{item:second_condition}
        Some other conditon.
    \end{enumerate}
    
    How I would imagine I could type it:
    \begin{theorem}
        \ref{item:first_condition}[7] holds.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        If \ref{item:second_condition}[n] holds, then \ref{item:first_condition}[n+2] holds.
    \end{theorem}
    
    How I would like it to look like:
    \begin{theorem}
        (i)$_7$ holds.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        If (ii)$_n$ holds, then (i)$_{n+2}$ holds.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the label and the `ref` output separately in enumitem, using both the `label` and the `ref` key for `\begin{enumerate}`. This can be used to show the *n* in the label but not in the reference. That allows you to reference the equation by the main number and adding your own subscript.

Now you can define a separate referencing command with two arguments, the equation and the subscript, using the command `\hyperref[target label]{link text}`.

To avoid a double link box you can disable the link for `\ref` using the star form (`\ref*`), and let `\hyperref` create the link box (or colorlink with `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`) for the combined label.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\nref}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\ref*{#1}$_{#2}$}}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    Consider the following conditions:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman{*})$_n$,ref=(\roman*)]
        \item
        \label{item:first_condition}
        Some condition
        \item
        \label{item:second_condition}
        Some other conditon.
    \end{enumerate}
    
    How I would imagine I could type it:
    \begin{theorem}
        \nref{item:first_condition}{7} holds.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        If \nref{item:second_condition}{n} holds, then \nref{item:first_condition}{n+2} holds.
    \end{theorem}
    
    How I would like it to look like:
    \begin{theorem}
        (i)$_7$ holds.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        If (ii)$_n$ holds, then (i)$_{n+2}$ holds.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's nice. I didn't know about the `ref=` option. Thanks!